# Remover mensagem default @Pattern JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jersey

Preciso de um help de vocês. Estou criando um web service rest em java utilizando jersey e hibernate. Para validar os campos informados por quem chama o serviço utilizei para um dos campos a anotação @Pattern da JPA, conforme abaixo:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Cfop {

@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "{cfop.idCfop.pattern}")
private String  idCfop;
...
```

A mensagem {cfop.idCfop.pattern} está definida no meu arquivo ValidationMessages.properties, conforme a seguir:

```
cfop.idCfop.pattern    = Id ${validatedValue} inv\u00e1lido.
```

E no meu Controller, tenho:

```
@Path(Constante.CFOP_SERVICE_ENDPOINT)
public class CfopController {

private final CfopRepository repository = new CfopRepository();


@POST
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
public Response Cadastrar(@Valid Cfop cfop){
```

Quando chamo o meu serviço via postman, ele imprime a mensagem certinho, contudo mostra tbm uma mensagem default, a qual eu não quero que seja exibida, conforme a seguir:

```
Id 123s inválido. (path = CfopController.Cadastrar.arg0.idCfop, invalidValue = 123s)
```

É possível suprimir essa mensagem: (path = CfopController.Cadastrar.arg0.idCfop, invalidValue = 123s) ?

Obs: No meu web.xml tenho:

```
  <init-param>
        <param-ame>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

Após muito bater cabeça, enfim consegui solucionar o meu problema para remover a mensagem. Antes de mais nada, percebi que a mensagem padrão do jersey, conforme o tópico acima, aparece para qualquer anotação (@NotBlank, @Size...) e não somente para @Pattern. Isso ocorre, pois na execução do serviço, para cada constraint violada (campos do meu bean que possuem as anotações) o jersey lança uma exceção do tipo ConstraintViolationException. Acontece, que ele já possui uma classe definida para quando esta exceção é disparada. Por esta razão, exibe a msg "indesejada" no output do serviço. Então, o que basicamente precisei fazer?  Precisei prover uma classe que implementasse um ExceptionMapper, cujo parâmetro fosse ConstraintViolationException e anotá-la com @Provider. Essa classe exige que implementemos o método toResponse o qual retorna um objeto do tipo Response. Então fiz:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements      ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {

    String msg= "";
    Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> itr =e.getConstraintViolations().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        ConstraintViolation<?> c =itr.next();
        msg += c.getMessage()+"\n";
    }

    return Response.status(400).entity(msg).build();
}
}
```

Em seguida, a única coisa a mais que precisei fazer foi indicar para o jersey em meu arquivo web.xml na tag init-param que ao executar ele deve procurar a minha classe no pacote indicado. Então, o que ele faz é procurar nesse meu pacote por classes anotas com @Provider. Assim, ele sabe que deve ser feito um override da classe de exceção que dispara o ConstraintViolationException. Vejam abaixo:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>coloque aqui o pacote onde estão as suas classes anotadas com @Path;coloque aqui o pacote com suas classes anotadas com @Provider</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Então é isso pessoal. Agradeço de qualquer forma o espaço cedido para minha dúvida e espero que seja útil para outros programadores a resposta. Abraço a todos.